# Swift Gesture recognizers added to textfield inoperable after becomes first responder?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uigesturerecognizer, tap

I added a tap and double tap gesture recognizer to a text field in swift, so that the single tap performs a function but the double tap actually makes the Textfield become first responder. it stops working though after the textfield becomes first responder for the first time. That is, the textfield operates as normally by becoming first responder on a single tap rather than double tap. Any ideas on how to keep my gesture recognizers working?

Comment: that logic makes no sense to me. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Textfield shows a countdown timer value. Single tap starts or pauses the timer. Double tap edits timer value. Feel free to suggest a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: See Tushar answer. Problem is editing the value? I'd use a method similar to apples implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach:

Just create an 'invisible' view on top of the textfield and add the gesture recognizers to it

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            textField.delegate = self;
        }

        override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            let tap1 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "onSingleTap")
            let tap2 = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "onDoubleTap")
            tap2.numberOfTapsRequired = 2

            // create a view and put it on top of the textfield
            // here created at viewDidAppear for example but you can do it better

            var dummieView = UIView(frame: self.textField.frame)
            dummieView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.25)
            self.view.addSubview(dummieView)
            dummieView.addGestureRecognizer(tap1)
            dummieView.addGestureRecognizer(tap2)
        }

        func onSingleTap(){
            println("custom single tap")
            if self.textField.isFirstResponder() {
                self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }

        func onDoubleTap(){
            println("double tap")
            self.textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            if self.textField.isFirstResponder() {
                self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
            return true
        }


    }
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks! Although that invisible view isn't quite invisible. Easy enough to fix though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Logically it would be easier if you follow these step instead:

1. set "editable" false to the texField
2. on doubleTap action implementation make the textfield editable to
   true and call becomeFirstResponder so that user can type.
3. implement textfield delegate method -textFieldDidEndEditing and again make that textField non-editable by setting "editable" property to false.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work. While uitextview has an "editable" field, uitextfield does not. And using the seemingly "enabled" field disables all touches so that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, wanting a single tap to alternate between displaying and hiding a UIPicker.

The problem is that UITextField adds its own gesture recognizers. So, subclass UITextField and add your own, but disallow the default gesture recognizers from being added.

```
class MyTextField: UITextField
{
    fileprivate var tap1Gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer?
    fileprivate var tap2Gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer?

    required init?( coder aDecoder: NSCoder )
    {
        super.init( coder: aDecoder )

        gestureRecognizers = nil
        tap1Gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer( target: self, action: #selector( tapped1( _: ) ) )
        addGestureRecognizer( tap1Gesture! )
        tap2Gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer( target: self, action: #selector( tapped2( _: ) ) )
        tap2Gesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        addGestureRecognizer( tap2Gesture! )
    }

    override func addGestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if gestureRecognizer == tap1Gesture || gestureRecognizer == tap2Gesture
        {
            super.addGestureRecognizer( gestureRecognizer )
        }
    }

    internal func tapped1( _ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer )
    {
        // Do your "performs a function"
    }

    internal func tapped2( _ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer )
    {
        if self.isFirstResponder
        {
            _ = self.resignFirstResponder()
        }
        else
        {
            self.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to hide selection of text, you can also add the following to your derived class (with help http://www.b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/disabling-the-caret-and-text-entry-in-uitextfields/):

```
extension MyTextField
{
    override var selectedTextRange: UITextRange?
    {
        get { return nil }
        set { return }
    }

    override func canPerformAction( _ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any? ) -> Bool
    {
        return false
    }

    override func caretRect( for position: UITextPosition ) -> CGRect
    {
        return .zero
    }
}
```